# How to divide *ngFor list of values into two divs

Tags: css, angular

IN angular How to divide *ngFor list of columns into two side by side divs.

```
set1=[1,2,3,4,5,6.....]
<div *ngFor="let person of set2">{{person }}</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify what your objective is, and what all codes you have written to achieve that. Then it will be helpful to give a solution

Comment: I guess you want two different columns. You can first make another set array based on your needs and use another ***ngFor** directive in two divs.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093786/using-angular2-ngfor-index/43093941

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### html

```
<div *ngFor="let person of set1; let ind = index;">
    <div *ngIf="ind % 2 == 0">
        {{set1[ind]}} - {{set1[ind+1]}}
    </div>
</div>
```

### ts

```
export class AppComponent {
    set1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
}
```

Comment: Quite similar to my answer

Comment: Looks optimize then yours.

Comment: Great, but may I know In what sense it is optimized? Also what, in case of  `ind%2 !==0`?

Comment: Why to ngIf needed bro?

Comment: Bro as per the question asked, He need to show each element but in different div. so in that we should need `ind%2 !==0` as well

Comment: Try my solution that gives you proper output.

Comment: Seems we both have different mindset on this solution dude, chill

Comment: Thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score 2):

try this -

```
<div *ngFor="let person of set1; let i = index">
<div *ngIf='i%2 === 0'>Even {{person}}</div>
<div *ngIf='i%2 !== 0'>Odd {{person}}</div>
</div>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/json-manipulate?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: how to make this side by side divs

Answer (score 0):

```
<div fxLayout="row" *ngFor="let person of set2; let i = index;" >
    <div fxFlex="50%" *ngIf="i<set2.length/2">
        {{person}}
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="50%" *ngIf="i>=set2.length/2">
        {{person}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PardeepJain No, it won't, I believe, because then it wont enter *ngFor at all

Answer (score 0):

You can also try if you know `true` condition...

```
<div *ngFor="let person of set1; let i = index">
   <div *ngIf="true-condition;else notTrue">IF {{person}}</div>
   <ng-template #notTrue>
     <div>Else {{person}}</div>
   </ng-template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58027002/10396570

Easy way: I am making the Angular demo Tour of Heroes and i wanted to divide in two columns the dashboard data *ngFor display;(like this) by ngFor

this is code it works for me right now:

```
<!--repeater creates as many links as
          are in the component's heroes array.-->
    <a *ngFor="let hero of heroes;" routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">       
      <!--ESTE STYLE SIRVE PARA QUE NO SE DEMADRE EL TAMAÑO DE CADA
      DIV, ELLIPSIS AYUDA EN ESTO-->
      <div style="
       width: 50%;
       float: left;
       white-space: nowrap;
       overflow: hidden;
       text-overflow: ellipsis;"
       class="module hero">
          {{hero.name}}            
      </div>         
    </a>
```